# loop through objects in django using template tags is not working

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-templates

I have model called Operation

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='Medicine')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', null = True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('home')
```

and views.py that looks like this

```
def Operation(request):
    return render(request, 'operation.html')

class OperationView(ListView):
    object_context_name = 'operation'
    model = Operation
    template_name = 'operation.html'

class OperationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Operation
    template_name= 'operation_details.html'
```

the html page that renders the Listview of all the operations is as follows

```
{% for operation in object_list %}
<article>
    <a href="{% url 'operation-detail' operation.pk %}" class="image"><img src="{{post.image}}" alt="" /></a>
    <h3>{{operation.title}}</h3> <br>
    <h6> {{operation.author}}</h6> <br>

    <p>{{operation.body | slice:":200"}}</p>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><a href="{% url 'operation-detail' operation.pk %}" class="button">More</a></li>
    </ul>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

However it's not working or rendering any operation articles on the page. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you delete your context_object_name your loop will work. But if you want to use that context_object_name you can edit your loop to:

```
{% for operations in operation %}
```

for more info: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you renamed your context object's name, either remove it or use {%for operation in operations%}